# Jasmine spyOn function that is called inside a callback

Tags: jquery, callback, jasmine

I have a class that loads an html and after this has loaded it calls a method, I want to test if the method have been called but since I am using jQuery load function and it is a callback the load is not executed until the SpecRunner has completed all the calls, therefore it doesn't know that the method was called

```
function A(){
    this.loadSomething(){
        $('#someId').load(something.html, function(){
            //Code here
            a.methodIWantToSeeIfWasCallled(); 
        });
    }
}
```

//Spec

```
describe("A", function(){
    it("should call to methodIWantToSeeIfWasCallled", function(){
        spyOn(a, "methodIWantToSeeIfWasCallled");
        a.loadSomething();
        expect(a.methodIWantToSeeIfWasCallled).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

Is there a way to make it finish the load before the test runs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine testing .load() to get called URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587790/jasmine-testing-load-to-get-called-url)