# Jasmine testing .load() to get called URL

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I have a function which loads a template and I want to check the correct URL is being called.

As I can't find any information other than for spying on ajax calls, I'm presuming it's the same for `.load()` calls. I'm using Jasmine 2.4.1

**Function**

```
function templateLoader() {
    var templateURL = '/path/to/template.html';
    $('#myElement').load(templateURL, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status === "error") {
            common.templateError(templateURL, xhr);
        } else {
            ns.successFunction();
        }
    });
}
```

**Jasmine Test**

```
var templateURL = '/path/to/template.html';
spyOn($('#myElement'), "load");
templateLoader(); // call the function
expect($('#myElement').load.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]).toEqual(templateURL);
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mostRecent' of undefined

Is there a different way to do this? I also want to check the success function is being called but until can check the URL is correct I can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Few Observations:**

- Your load is an ajax function, so you'd have to `spyOn` `$.ajax`
  rather than `$(#myElement).load`
- You cannot check both the call URL & the successCallBack at the same
  time without mocking the ajax function itself. This is because your
  successCallback gets executed only after you get a response from
  server, meanwhile your test runs through.
- Hence the trick is to mock the ajax call itself and call a fakeFunction to resolve the promise, which actually resolves the success value at run-time i.e. synchronously- which aids your expectations.

**Note:**
I used jasmine 2.5

The code below illustrates all the points mentioned above. To see it in action, reach out to the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/19/)

```
function templateLoader(templateURL) {
  $('#myElement').load(templateURL, null, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "error") {
      common.templateError(templateURL, xhr);
    } else {
      successFunction();
    }
  });
}

successFunction = function() {
  console.log("This is a success Function");
}

describe("spec to test ajax url", function() {
  it('test load call url', function() {
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(window, 'successFunction').and.callThrough();
    templateLoader("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    expect($.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]).toEqual("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");    
  });

  it('test success function', function(){
    spyOn(window, 'successFunction').and.callThrough();
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(e) {
      return new $.Deferred().resolve({}).promise();
    });
    templateLoader("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    expect($.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]).toEqual("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");    
    expect(window.successFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```